# can't get the first column value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have small csv file which look like this:

```
name,email,year,month,day
Test,test@outlook.com,1961,4,9
Test2,test@gyahoo.com,1980,3,25
Test3,test3@gmail.com,1980,8,19
Test4,test4@gmail.com,1984,4,9
```

i want to get the item that the date equal to today date, but when i try to print row.name in the code below i get only the index (0, 3 in this case) and not the actual name (which need to be Test, Test4)

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas

today = dt.datetime.now()
month = today.month
day = today.day

data = pandas.read_csv("birthdays.csv")
for (index, row) in data.iterrows():
    if (row.month == month) & (row.day == day):
        print(row.name)
```

why is that?
thanks

Comment: `pd.Series.name` is a built-in attribute (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.name.html). You should use the indexing syntax here: `row["name"]` to get the name you're looking for.

Comment: thank you! maybe i just change the column name to fisrt_name..

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is:

```py
for (index, row) in data.iterrows():
    if (row.month == month) & (row.day == day):
        #print the name of the person whose birthday is today
        print(row[0])
```

row.name isn't printing the name but rather the index as you know.  because the 'row' object has an attribute called 'name'.  if you are dead set on wanting to use row.name you can change it to a dict.

```py
for (index, row) in data.iterrows():
    if (row.month == month) & (row.day == day):
        #change row to a dict
        row = row.to_dict()
        #print the name
        print(row["name"])
```

Comment: i changed the column to "first_name" and used dictionary comprehension: emails = {row.first_name:row.email for (index, row) in data.iterrows() if (row.month == month) & (row.day == day)}